# Text explanation

Tags: reading-comprehension

I'm studying by my textbook 日本語総まとめ 読解 (N3) and faced this exercise. The correct answer is 1 and 5. But I don't understand why the answer 4 is incorrect. Apparently, I'm missing something, but I read this text many times and still don't understand.

[image]

Comment: If Sentence 4 were "この学生たちはドラッグストア**に向かうための交差点**を通り過ぎてしまったようだ", then it would be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general 通り過ぎる implies you were in the proximity of that thing. In this case they didn't come close to the pharmacy, so you wouldn't normally use 通り過ぎる.